# Is it possible to use `S3 storage` as HDF5 file storage and share it with other server?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hdf5, pytables

I'm gonna get tons of data via Stock API (by Korean Stock company) and trying to store all of them as `HDF5 format` using `Python PyTable`. And there is another server running `Django` web application. This web app gonna use those HDF5 datas.

But there are some limitations:

> **1. API is only available in `Window OS`**
>
> **2. Data(`pandas` or `numpy` form) must be stored as `HDF5` format. Not using SQL Database**

This is how system looks:

1. Data generator

   - Window OS computer board such as LattePanda.(http://www.lattepanda.com/)
   - or `AWS window EC2(?)`   # Not sure about this. Need your advices
2. Data storage : `AWS S3`
3. Web application : `AWS EC2`

So, `LattePanda` is running on my home and it gets stock datas periodically. And it store them in `AWS S3`. `Django` web application run on EC2 gonna fetch these datas and render them on templates.

Are those optimal system composition?